# How do base stats differ between classes?

Tags: destiny

I was reading [a forum](http://www.polygon.com/forums/destiny/2014/9/24/6838391/clans-of-polygon-whats-going-on-in-destiny-september-part-ii) that said the Warlock class was "squishier", a "glass cannon". Is this true? How was anyone able to tell the difference?

What are the base stat differences between the classes (Warlock, Hunter, Titan), and how are they measured? For instance, how does health or base damage output differ between classes? Or if the "agility" stat is equivalent across several classes, is their agility the same, or does the class add a buff? Or is calling the Warlock class "squishier" more about the way their ults/super powers deal damage?

Comment: I've certainly noticed my Warlock being squishier than other classes, but given how you can choose the way your stats are modified as you level that might be a result of my idea of how I want to play rather than a core difference. The biggest thing that makes my Hunter my least squishy character is that the way her jump works allows me to escape situations that the Titan and Warlock simply cant. The Warlock especially is just a slow moving target during double jump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at your skills, there's three stats at the top: Armor, Recovery, Agility.
Titans start out with more Armor.
Hunters start out with more Agility.
Warlocks start out with more Recovery.

As you level, you can choose skills that increase one or more of these stats.  You could compensate for a lower stat by picking skills that increase that stat.  I don't know how much these increase compared to the starting value (i.e. if a Warlock focused on Armor could they match the starting value of a Titan?)

I'm not sure how much difference the stats make, numbers-wise, but I do have some ancedotal evidence.
As a Titan, I have been able to sustain more damage and take hits that would kill my Warlock friends. I've taken the skills that increase all stats and Armor/Recovery.
As a starting Warlock, the time I wait to regen is noticeably shorter than my Titan.